# Does hadoop and spark support IPv6 now?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, ipv6

I want to build Hadoop and Spark cluster over a pure IPv6 environment. I have already built it over IPv4, how can I configure to run them under IPv6 environment？Do hadoop and spark support IPv6 now?

Comment: Have you tried it already? Did you encounter any issues? Can you prepare a  [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

It does not. As of today [HADOOP-11890](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11890), which track progress of IPv6 support, is still unresolved.