# Spark Master lookup stalling on ipv6 lookup of localhost in Standalone mode

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am running a Spark Standalone with `local` master:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("SparkSingleStagePipeline").getOrCreate
```

This had been working without issues but now is hanging on local ipv6 lookup.  This was discovered by doing a thread dump against the (hanging) spark process and seeing the `main` thread stopped here:

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fed6200b000 nid=0x1c03 runnable [0x000070000ef68000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
    - locked <0x000000076f5d1f98> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:884)
```

This is not a duplicate of [Does hadoop and spark support IPv6 now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054959/does-hadoop-and-spark-support-ipv6-now) because this problem has only recently surfaced and that other question only actually addresses `hadoop`.

Do I need to disable `ipv6` on this machine ( `Macbook Pro` with `El Capitan`) ?

**Update** This issue is intermittent and seems to also be affected by whether running at home or in the office.

Comment: @user8371915  It is *not* a duplicate. Please understand the scenario better before the vote to close.

Comment: @javadba Spark relies on Hadoop ;) Try to add preferIPv4 to Java Options and see if it works - should

Comment: @T.Gawęda "Spark relies on Hadoop" - Is that a for real comment?  Spark handles networking separately/differently than Hadoop. The spark dependency on hadoop is for input/output data formats.

Comment: Yes, I know it uses Netty. But problems may be very similar. And comment about Hadoop was just to show why other people may think it's a duplicate

Comment: Ok that is more clear comment:  spark actually did not always use `netty`.